# Block disappears if there is no image in it

Tags: javascript

All health and happiness! A written script that should iterate through all the pictures, if the pictures did not load, then the script should hide the parent block under the **.Parent_block** class, that is, I have 3 blocks, there is a picture in the central block, but not in the other two, which means they should have property **display:none**

**But I did something wrong. Where did I make a mistake?**

```js
let parent_block = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block');
let image_b = document.querySelectorAll('.Child_Img');

image_b.forEach(function(){

if(image_b.onerror){

for(let parent_block of hide){
hide.style.display = 'none';    
}

}

})
```

```css
.Parent_block{
width:30%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
border:1px solid black;
display:inline-block;
height:250px;
}

img{
height:inherit;
width:100%;
```

```html
<figure class="Parent_block"> <!-- ***** this block should disappear *****  =( -->
 
<img class="Child_Img" src="">

<figcaption class ="Img_text">1</figcaption> 

</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block"> 
 
<img class="Child_Img" src="https://i.ibb.co/kyXhZmB/photo-2021-11-18-14-40-18.jpg">

<figcaption class ="Img_text">2</figcaption> 

</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block"> <!-- ***** and this one too *****  =( -->
 
<img class="Child_Img" src="">

<figcaption class ="Img_text">3</figcaption> 

</figure>
```

Comment: `onerror` is an *event*, not a boolean property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with the script.

- You are running `image_b.forEach` and inside that you are trying to access `image_b.onerror`. This will not work since `image_b` is an array.
- `onerror` is an event and not a property. So it cannot be accessed like this.
- The syntax `for(let parent_block of hide)` is wrong.

**Fixed Code**

*Logic*

- Select all elements with class name `Child_Img`.
- Loop through the elements and register `onerror` event on each element in the list that we selected with class name `Child_Img`.
- On the error event, find the closest element with class name `Parent_block` and hide it.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let image_b = document.querySelectorAll('.Child_Img');
image_b.forEach(function (img) {
    img.onerror = function(image) {
        img.closest(".Parent_block").style.display = 'none';
    }
})
```

```css
.Parent_block {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
}

img {
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<figure class="Parent_block">
    <!-- ***** this block should disappear *****  =( -->

    <img class="Child_Img" src="">

    <figcaption class="Img_text">1</figcaption>

</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">

    <img class="Child_Img" src="https://i.ibb.co/kyXhZmB/photo-2021-11-18-14-40-18.jpg">

    <figcaption class="Img_text">2</figcaption>

</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block">
    <!-- ***** and this one too *****  =( -->

    <img class="Child_Img" src="">

    <figcaption class="Img_text">3</figcaption>

</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

- [on error - read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)
- [closest - read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
let parent_block = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block');
let image_b = document.querySelectorAll('.Child_Img');

image_b.forEach(function(image){
   // check if any error (if image doesn't load in our case)
   image.addEventListener("error",()=>{
      // find closest class name and hide it
      image.closest(".Parent_block").style.display = "none";
   })
})
```

```css
.Parent_block{
width:30%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:10px;
border:1px solid black;
display:inline-block;
height:250px;
}

img{
height:inherit;
width:100%;
```

```html
<figure class="Parent_block"> <!-- ***** this block should disappear *****  =( -->
 
<img class="Child_Img" src="">

<figcaption class ="Img_text">1</figcaption> 

</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block"> 
 
<img class="Child_Img" src="https://i.ibb.co/kyXhZmB/photo-2021-11-18-14-40-18.jpg">

<figcaption class ="Img_text">2</figcaption> 

</figure>


<figure class="Parent_block"> <!-- ***** and this one too *****  =( -->
 
<img class="Child_Img" src="">

<figcaption class ="Img_text">3</figcaption> 

</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of problems with your script.
Some examples:

1. `onerror` should not be checked with `if`, but with event listener.
2. `forEach` needs an argument, you haven't provided any.
3. You should add `.onerror` to the argument of `foreach`, and not directly to `image_b`
4. There is no variable declared as `hide` in your script. I am guessing you intended `for (let hide of parent_block)`
5. Assuming you fixed everything up to #4, the loop runs `hide.style.display = 'none'` for *everything* of parent_block, and not just the ones that includes the images with errors.

The following should work:

```
let parent_block = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block');
let image_b = document.querySelectorAll('.Child_Img');

image_b.forEach(function (cur_image) { 
    cur_image.onerror = function () {
        for(let block of parent_block){
            if(block.contains(cur_image) ){
                block.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    } 
})
```

But the loop over the `parent_block` is not necessary, you can just find the relevant ancestor of the `cur_image`:

```
// let parent_block = document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block');
let image_b = document.querySelectorAll('.Child_Img');

image_b.forEach(function (cur_image) { 
    cur_image.onerror = function () {
        let hide = cur_image.closest('.Parent_block')
        hide.style.display = 'none';
    } 
})
```

Note that it's not even to required to run `document.querySelectorAll('.Parent_block')` anymore.

Answer (score 2):

A very minimal solution could be done in the HTML. Remove all of your JS, and just change the `<img>` tags like so:

```
<img class="Child_Img" src="" onerror="this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';">
```